# Get rid of extra boxes in cgloss4e

Tags: linguex, cgloss4e

I notice that glosses using the `\twosent` macro in `cgloss4e` have an extra, phantom "word" at the end. I use the following code to add a small rule indicating where each word box starts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{cgloss4e} % (loaded by linguex but added for clarity)
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\eachwordone{\rule[-2pt]{2pt}{6pt}}
\renewcommand*\eachwordtwo{\rule[-2pt]{2pt}{6pt}}
\ex.
\gll    con heo \\
    animal  pig \\
\glt    `pig'   \par
\end{document}
```

[image]

A third word box appears although there are only two words in the arguments to `\gll`. This phantom word box is undesirable because if it appears by itself on a line, it causes unnecessary vertical space between the gloss line and the free translation.
The effect can be appreciated by inserting the following line into the preamble of the above code:

```
\usepackage[showframe,textwidth=1.2in]{geometry}
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to get `cgloss4e` to make one word box less?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\twosent` creates two vertical boxes containing the first and second lines with the following call to `\getwords`.

```
\getwords(\lineone,\eachwordone)#1 \\%
\getwords(\linetwo,\eachwordtwo)#2 \\%
```

`\getwords` is defined with the following argument context:

```
\gdef\getwords(#1,#2)#3 #4\
```

The call to `\getwords` in `\twosent` introduces a space to prevent TeX from producing an error in case the user were to enter the example without spaces between the final word and the newline characters, i.e.:

```
 \gll    con     heo\\
          animal  pig\\
          `pig'   \par
```

In fact, if input is entered this way, then no empty box is created at the end.

[image]

So there are two options for fixing the situation:

1. Code all examples with no space between the final word and the line break character. You will receive no warning if your examples are set with an empty box.
2. Remove the "safety" space from the calls to `\getwords` in `\twosent` (and  `\threesent`, if `\glll` is being used). You will never get empty boxes at the end, but TeX will complain if you ever fail to have a space before the newline character. Also, if the last word ends in a control sequence, the control sequence should be bracketed lest the following space be ignored.